# deleting dynamic table rows in android

Tags: android, tablerow

in my app, i have created  table rows dynamically

in each table row, i provide an icon that will help the user help in deleting that specific row

how can i achieve this? any suggestions please

is there a better option than using `setVisibility()`?

i tried `setTag()` and `setId()`, but it doesn't seem to work after one row is deleted, since the id values remain same after deletion

hope my question is well understood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lets assume your layout is like this.

```
<TableRow>
<Icon>
</Icon>
</TableRow>
```

your icon view can be anything ImageView or ImageButton. since you din't post any xml. i am just referring as icon.

Now, how to access the table row to delete?

on the onClick event. you get access to the icon view.

```
  TableRow tr = (TableRow)iconview.getParent();
```

will give access to the parent view after which you can perform deletions on this view.

Comment: wow lovely!!  wat a quick and precise answer! thanks.. this is the 2nd time u ve helped me out